# How to execute an action in onException block before onRedelivery in camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an onException block in a camel route. It looks like this:

```
...
.onException(SomeException.class)
.maximumRedeliveries(3)
.redeliveryDelay(5000)
.onRedelivery(e -> {log()})
.retryAttemptedLogLevel(WARN)
.process(e -> {log()})
.handled(true)
...
```

The problem is that the redeliveries are executed before the process.
I would like to do something before retry. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you not able to achieve that using onRedelivery?

Comment: No, It fires onRedelivery at the first retry(attempt 1), after 5 sec from the attempt 0. I want to do something immediately after attempt 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77094915/how-to-execute-an-action-in-onexception-block-before-onredelivery-in-camel?noredirect=1#comment135925077_77094915:%7E:text=No%2C%20It%20fires%20onRedelivery%20at%20the%20first%20retry(attempt%201)%2C%20after%205%20sec%20from%20the%20attempt%200.%20I%20want%20to%20do%20something%20immediately%20after%20attempt%200) to perform action immediately after exception. you can use .onExceptionOccurred() processor, which executes immediately after exception, whereas onRedelivery() executes before retry. You can refer [docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_using_onexceptionoccurred_processor) for more info.

```
...
.onException(SomeException.class)
.onExceptionOccurred(e -> {log()})
.maximumRedeliveries(3)
.redeliveryDelay(5000)
.onRedelivery(e -> {log()})
.retryAttemptedLogLevel(WARN)
.process(e -> {log()})
.handled(true);
...
```

Comment: Just what I was searching for. Thanks!